# Somar valor se uma coluna conrresponder a uma outra coluna e se ela pertencer a uma outra coluna

Tags: lógica, condição, filter, google-sheets, fórmula

Estou tendo dificuldade em pensar e achar uma formula que resolva esse problema de logica no google sheets.

Tenho uma planilha (A) cheio de dados e outra (B) que só seleciono os dados da planilha (A) usando a validação de dados.

Uma vez selecionado o item desejado na planilha (B)B2:B quero que verifique se esse dado pertence a uma pessoa especifica da planilha (A)D2:D especificado na celula J13,J14,J15... se sim, somar os respectivos valores selecionados na planilha (B)D2:D **apenas** pertencentes a essa pessoa.

Primeiramente imaginei de usar a função: FILTER + SOMA para selecionar os itens pertencentes a uma pessoa especifica e somar os valores selecionados

```
=SOMA(FILTER('PLANILHA A'!F2:F;'PLANILHA A'!B2:B=B2:B;'PLANILHA A'!D2:D=J13))
```

OR

```
=SOMA(FILTER('PLANILHA A'!F2:F;FILTER('PLANILHA A'!B2:B; 'DB Equipamentos'!D2:D=J13)=B2:B))
```

O Resultado obtido foi apenas a soma de todos valor selecionado da coluna B2:B. Se reduzir a formula para:

```
=SOMA(FILTER('PLANILHA A'!F2:F;'PLANILHA A'!D2:D=J13))
```

A formula funciona como esperado, somando os valores da planilha (A)F2:F se o nome da pessoa for igual a celula J13. Estou cometendo algum erro de sintax? exite alguma outra funcão + apropriada para resolver essa questão??

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.